# Android app bar and toolbar elevation issues

Tags: android, toolbar, elevation, tabbed

[The image of the app before swiping on the action bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP8t9.png)   [The image of the app after swiping on the action bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hsHK.png) I am making a simple tabbed view application in android studio. The app works fine until I swipe up on the action bar to hide it and the elevation seems to be off. Here is the activity resource file. `

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:elevation = "0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

` 
Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks...